# NSFetchRequest - get all objects by relationship

Tags: objective-c, core-data, relationship, nsfetchrequest

It's possible create a`NSFetcherRequest` or something similar for get all objects by relationship? For example I have three entities student, absence and subject. Student has attributes `NSSet` absence, absence has attribute student and subject. I need get all absence of one student and one subject. So I need require similar this pseudo code: **select all absence where student=="concrete student" and where subject=="concrete subject"**. But it aren't attributes, but relationship! How can I do it? I know, that I can get all absence of student and than filter it, but I think, its very inefficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both *attributes* and *relationships* are *properties* of a managed object and
can be used as key path in a predicate, for example:

```
 Student *concreteStudent = ...;
 Subject *concreteSubject = ...;
 NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"student = %@ AND subject = %@",
     concreteStudent, concreteSubject];
 NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Absence"];
 fetchRequest.predicate = predicate;
```

if "student" and "subject" are to-one relationships of the Absence entity.